# Java: check if the mouse has clicked

Tags: java, mouse, click

i am in trouble with checking if the mouse has clicked with a JFrame. When i use `public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` to print something and i click with the mouse it doesn't print anything. It doesn't gives a error, it just prints nothing out. Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class tuna extends JFrame
{
private JTextArea textArea;



public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //Run the program
tuna run = new tuna();
run.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
run.setSize(1200, 1000);

run.setVisible(true);
}

public tuna()
{


  super("Simple JFrame");

  //add a simple JScrollPane
  textArea = new JTextArea(10,10);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
  textArea.setEditable(true);

  add(scrollPane);

}
//This doesn't print anything when i am clicking in the JFrame
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        System.out.println("left");
    }       
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
    {
      System.out.println("right");
    }
}


}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Event Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html). Just writing a `mousePressed()` method wont help to handle mouse click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can make you own Mouse Listener and add it to textArea or another component.
For example like this:

```
    public class tuna extends JFrame
{
    private JTextArea textArea;



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Run the program
        tuna run = new tuna();
        run.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        run.setSize(1200, 1000);

        run.setVisible(true);
    }

    public tuna()
    {


        super("Simple JFrame");

        //add a simple JScrollPane
        textArea = new JTextArea(10,10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.addMouseListener(new CustomListener());


        add(scrollPane);

    }
    //This doesn't print anything when i am clicking in the JFrame
    public class CustomListener implements MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if(mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                System.out.println("left");
            }
            else if(mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            {
                System.out.println("right");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Well there are few issues, in your concept and source code

   First you need a `MouseListener`, so in your case either you can
   create a separate `MouseListener` or use the current `JFrame` class
   itself, like this

   `public class Tuna extends JFrame implements MouseListener`
2. Also I would recommend to follow proper naming convention and use `Tuna`  instead of `tuna`.
3. Then the element you want to respond on the `MouseEvents` should be
   register with the `MouseListener` created in first step, in your constructor.

   `textArea.addMouseListener(this);`
4. Also make sure on what element you want to register your
   `MouseListener`, currently your entire Frame is covered by TextArea,
   so registering listener on `JFrame` won't help, instead add it on
   `JTextArea`
5. Try using `@Override` annotation where ever possible, editor shows
   appropriate compiler errors then, in your case you just wrote,

   `public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)`

   instead of

   `@Override`

   `public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)`

   As this methods works only if you implement an `MouseListener`

Refer this link for more understanding,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html